# Pass value from class method to a react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, class, data-binding

**Situation:** I have a class with its own methods. This class is instantiated in a React component.

**What I'm needing:** During one of the methods in the class, it changes the value of an input (`this.$el`) using `.val()`, but I'm listening to changes to this input in the React.component via `onChange`. I need to pass the value I'm using to set the value of the input (via `this.$el.val(value)`) to the React component to change its state.

**What I've tried:** I've tried chaining `.change()` and `trigger('change')` to the `val(value)`, but it doesn't have any affect.

So, I need to be able to access the value I'm using in `.val(value)` in my React component WHEN it is set in the class method. I thought about using a method and calling that method on `componentWillUpdate`, but the component doesn't update since setting the input value via `val()` doesn't trigger a change.

Any ideas?

**Component code:**

```
// Create a ref to manage blur/focus state on the search input
this.inputRef = React.createRef()
// Setup initial state
this.state = {
  supersearchResults: [],
  value: this.props.initialValue || ''
}
this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this)

tag('input', {
      autoComplete: 'off',
      className: blockElement('search-input'),
      onChange: this.onInputChange,
      placeholder: 'Find people, collections and pages',
      ref: this.inputRef,
      type: 'text',
      value: this.state.value
 })
```

**Class code:**
`this` = class
`this.$el` = input

```
// What is happening:
// A user types in an input, suggestions display in a list, when you
// select a suggestion, it calls the below to change the input value
this.$el.val(complete)
this.$el.blur()
this.hide()
```

Comment: Can you add more code to understand?

Comment: Added more. Should be enough

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to access the value of a html field. Then please take into consideration the following considerations. Use controlled inputs such that the

```
class ReactComponent extends...
    constuctor (props) {
        super();
        this.state = { fieldValue: props.fieldValue || '' };
    }

    onFieldChange = (event) => {
       this.setState('fieldValue': event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    render () {
        return (
           <div>
                <input type="text"
                    value={this.state.fieldValue}
                    onChange={this.onFieldChange}
                >
           <div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now having this code, in case you need to use some external class to call some code, simply put it correctly in the lifecycle. But in order to reference the value use the components state. And in case you want to programmatically want to change the value, do the same update the value in the state. If I missed something let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the state in your class component. consider the following

```
class TextExample extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      username: null
    }
    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  _handleChange(e){
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ username: value}) // for single TextField
    // if you want to reuse this _handleChange function for all the TextFields then you need to use the below commented code which updates state of current TextField

   //this.setState({ [name]: value })  // it is similar like the JSON bracket notation 
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="username"
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this._handleChange}   // it will call the _handleChange function on every keypress inside the TextField. 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have this, but because `onChange` isn't fired when the class method calles `.val()`, it doesn't set. I'm looking to pass the value I'm passing to `.val()` to the component to set the state using it.

Comment: Can you show your class component. Which will be helpful for us